# credentials stored securely in the report server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, account-management

Does anyone know the least windows account previlege to run under "credentials stored securely in the report server" option in the report manager?

I have tried to create a windows account with admin right and assign to "credentials stored securely in the report server" option but didn't work. However I enter administrator account, it works ok.. confusing.. can anyone please help?

Comment: The credentials stored in teh report server is about SQL Server users rather than reporting services permissions. If you are using a fixed user in the connection then this might sound silly but have you added the new user to SQL Server permissions? (SSRS doesnt do it for you automatically.) 

Or are you get authentication to the website issues (prompt for AD credentials?)

Comment: Not sure with ur answer.. btw in the report manager you can specify the windows account under "credentials stored securely in the report server" for the RS to access the SQL server. If I entered the administrator account in "credentials stored securely in the report server" and clicked on "Test Connection", it worked ok.. However when I entered another windows account with admin privelege, it didn't work when I clicked on "test connection".. do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the report Data Source in SSRS to use "credentials stored securely in the report server"; go back to SSMS, connect to the database instance, and set up a new Security login with the Windows account.  Check the database and select the db_datareader and db_executor to provide read-only rights to report users.

Answer (score 0):

@u07ch is probably spot on.  the reason the admin account works and the other doesn't is probably because the admin is set up as an admin on the sql server, which by default grants it unlimited rights to the databases.

to fix your issue, you need to log into sql server, at the account you want to use for the report at the server level, assign it to the database/s the report access, and grant the account sufficient privileges on the database to exec and select.